# How do I make Adobe Acrobat Reader 9 to be my default Internet Explorer PDF plugin?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, internet-explorer, adobe-reader, foxit-reader

I have 2 PDF apps installed: Adobe Reader 9 and Foxit PDF Reader.  For whatever reason, Foxit PDF Reader is the default PDF plugin for Internet Explorer.

How do I make Adobe Reader 9 to be the default PDF plugin (short of uninstalling Foxit or reinstalling Adobe Reader)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying various suggested methods, here is the only thing that actually worked:

1. Control Panel
2. Add/Remove Programs
3. Locate Adobe Reader, click Change/Remove
4. Select Repair

Magic, it worked.  The PDFs in IE invoke the Adobe Reader plugin.

Comment: Had you installed Foxit after installing Adobe? If so it'll be the last installed reader that overwrites the IE plugin information. That explains why a repair of Adobe fixed the problem.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, that is probably the case.

Answer (score 1):

Only this works.

Disable Web Browser Integration.

1. In Acrobat or Adobe Reader, choose Edit > Preferences > Internet.
2. Deselect Display PDF in Browser, and then click OK.

Comment: I don't think this answer really addresses the original question, but it helped me solve a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to right click a pdf file and change it's association (under properties)? I tested and it worked (I also have foxit and adobe, even though I prefer foxit).

right click > properties. The file properties window will appear. Choose the General tab. You'll see a field called "Opens with". Click the change button and select the program that you prefer. This instructions are based on a Windows XP OS.

You can also try to open IE, and under tools > manage add-ons verify whats configured and change it.

Comment: Under what Properties?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what program is associated with the .PDF file extension.

My Computer --> Tools --> Folder Options --> File Types tab --> Highlight the .PDF extension in the list and view which program opens it by default and change it if necessary.

Comment: This is XP. Your method did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file you want to open - Choose "Open With" then select "Choose Default Program." Select Abode Reader, then select OK and you're done. Hope this helps

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The question asks for a solution to set the default plugin and not default file association.